# Nested blocks and references to self

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, weak-references

I have a block wherein I use `self` so I declare a weak reference to self:

```
__weak MyClass *weakSelf = self;
```

Now my questions:

1. I get an error where I define `weakSelf` and I don't understand what this should mean.:

   weak attribute can not be specified on an automatic variable
2. Inside my block I pass `weakSelf` to another block and I am not sure if I now have to do the same thing again like so:

   ```
   __weak MyClass *weakWeakSelf = weakSelf;
   ```

   And then pass `weakWeakSelf` to that block?

Comment: Have you found the answer for this yet? The weakWeakSelf part I mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is most likely occurring as you are targeting down to iOS 4. You should change it to be

```
__unsafe_unretained MyClass *weakWeakSelf = weakSelf;
```

Comment: Funny if I change my `Deployment target` to < 5.0 I get the error you had. but above that it is fine. Did this resolve the issue?

Comment: Do I have to declare weakWeakSelf too?

Answer (score 3):

**With ARC**

```
__weak __typeof__(self) wself = self;
```

**Wihtout ARC**

```
__unsafe_unretained __typeof__(self) wself = self;
```

Answer (score 1):

With [libextobjc](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc) it will be readable and easy:

```
- (void)doStuff
{
    @weakify(self); 
    // __weak __typeof__(self) self_weak_ = self;

    [self doSomeAsyncStuff:^{

        @strongify(self);
        // __strong __typeof__(self) self = self_weak_;

        // now you don't run the risk of self being deallocated
        // whilst doing stuff inside this block 
        // But there's a chance that self was already deallocated, so
        // you could want to check if self == nil

        [self doSomeAwesomeStuff];

        [self doSomeOtherAsyncStuff:^{

            @strongify(self);
            // __strong __typeof__(self) self = self_weak_;

            // now you don't run the risk of self being deallocated
            // whilst doing stuff inside this block 
            // Again, there's a chance that self was already deallocated, so
            // you could want to check if self == nil

            [self doSomeAwesomeStuff];

        }];
    }];
}
```