# Objective-C ARC __weak variable reference triggers warning "__weak attribute cannot be specified on an automatic variable"

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c++, weak-references

I've got an app (only ios5) that inside a method declares a weak variable used inside a block to reference an instance of a view controller.

```
 QRCodeViewController * __weak weakSelf = self;
```

The problem is that the compiler shows a warning saying:

> __weak attribute cannot be specified on an automatic variable

In that application I've used a lot weak references and I never saw a warning like that, the only difference from the other classes is that this class is implemented in a .mm file since it uses a c++ object and project can't compile if I leave it as a .m. 
I must say that the code seems to work fine.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `__weak QRCodeViewController *weakSelf = self;` ?

Comment: @Martin either one works, they are equivalent, your way is the one I see used more frequently, but Andrea's way is the one recommended by Apple.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431110/nested-blocks-and-references-to-self.  Answer there was that the deployment target was set to 4.0, but that's not the case for you. Correct?

Comment: Hello, my deployment target is >ios5 only. About the syntax as Analog File wrote they both give the same warning.

Comment: You are doing this **outside** the block that uses it, aren't you?

Comment: Does you have given any @property assigned as (atomic) in .h file for QRCodeViewController ??

Comment: Yes is outside the definition of the block, all the properties declare in .h are (strong, nonatomic) and also properties declared in the .m are (strong, non atomic). THX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facing this same warning, I make it disappear using a __block attribute the following way :

```
__block __weak MyViewController* weakSelf = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the warning says that `__weak` cannot be specified. AFAIK it should be possible to specify it, even if it's very dangerous to use `__weak` for automatic variables.

Apple documentation says that the compiler will provide a warning if you do, but the actual warning text seems to imply that the attribute is going to be ignored not merely that using it is dangerous, while the documentation seems to imply that it's dangerous but it works as expected (if you really understand what to expect).

You'll have to do some experimentation to verify if the warning text is inappropriate or if the documentation has not been correctly updated.

Comment: Hi Analog File, thanks for your answer, the fact is that is normal to create weak references for objects that you want to pass to a Block to avoid retain cycles. I did tons of times in my code without any warning. I agree that weak for an automatic variable is dangerous, or better is a non-sense, because when you will use in a block for async process the variable is gone since it doesn't have a strong reference to it. But here I'm assigning self that is not an automatic variable and that is strong referenced by the existence of the class itself.

Comment: It's not a nonsense. As you say it has perfectly reasonable use cases. But it's dangerous. Your async block example is spot on (a lot of people would have problems understanding why it does not work). That's the rationale behind Apple choice to make it legal and yet spit out a warning. If you verified that it works, I guess the problem is mostly in the warning text, not in the fact that you get the warning (which is a conscious decision of the compiler developers according to the docs). That's also why it's just a warning even if it's worded as an error.

Comment: @AnalogFile: Do you have a reference to the Apple documentation where it is said that the compiler emits a warning if __weak is used with automatic variables? Thank you!